# Why appears a question mark "?" when I try to change my wordpress url acces to cpanel?? (wps hide plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, controls, admin

I recently installed a plugin in wordpress "WPS HIDE" to change my url acces to control panel (cpanel), this would be the result:

- https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin
  changing to
- https://yourdomain.com/elarthur

I wanted to do that but WPS HIDE plugin add an extra "?" in the url like this

- https://yourdomain.com/?elarthur

Note that "?" added, cant be erased, I saw oyutube tutorials without that error, somebody can help me with that? Thanks

I want to know if is possible to erase that "?", only that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to the `Permalink` settings. Under `Permalink` settings, make sure you aren’t using the `Plain` option.

You can find that from the sidebar, under `Settings` → `Permalinks`, or at the direct URL, substituting your domain for the placeholder.:

```
<domain>/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
```

Once the permalink is set to use any of the options other than plain, it will work for you.